# Ralink RT3290 Wi-Fi drivers missing after install

Tags: wifi, drivers

I just installed the latest elementary OS and am missing Wi-Fi drivers. My chip is a ***Ralink RT3290***. I've tried practically every guide which apparently 'solves' this issue, but none have worked thus far.
I get errors while doing the 'sudo make' step in the solution mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104690) and nothing seems to be able to fix that. Hoping someone here has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy seems to have the solution.

Download the file
http://onthim.blogspot.ca/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html

and follow the instructions in ReadMe inside the RT3290 folder.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The solution worked!
Only thing is, ReadMe asks you to run Run.sh, which doesn't work. Instead, run setup.sh and all will be fine. 
Thankyou so much!

Comment: I'm glad it worked.