# WiFi is not working on Loki

Tags: release-loki, wifi

I have just installed elementary OS Loki and it looks great. I have one problem though. WiFi is not working.
During installation it worked perfectly and I was able to connect to my home network and check on the boxes for download updates & third party software.
Now my laptop WiFi button's LED is yellow instead of white and it says WiFi is disabled.
What should I do?

Comment: So I reinstalled without connecting during this process. It keeps my driver and WiFi works just fine. But then I type sudo apt get update and I restart. Now WiFi is not working again. So I guess there are 2 drivers and after update it uses the 2nd one which is not working. I can t understand since I used Ubuntu a lot from 14.04 to 16.04 and I had no problems. What is wrong with elementary os?

Comment: Without information about your hardware, it is impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: so basically I've got a RT3290 network adapter, tried installing a driver from different websites with different methodes, had no luck.
But it's quite odd that with Ubuntu 16.04 it works just fine ( isn't Loki based on Ubuntu? )
And main point is that after install WiFi worked just fine, but I had no apps in AppCenter others than default ones, so I typed get update in a terminal then restarted and poof, full of apps in AppCenter but Wifi isn't working anymore ( connected with a cable ethernet ). Any thoughts?
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried filing a bug report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink RT3290 Wi-Fi drivers missing after install](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7149/5565)

Comment: Is it a macbook?

Comment: This does not help my situation as I do not see a yes in anything for a soft blocked. I am still unable to access the internet, but it says I am connected?

Comment: Looks like filing a bug is not possible (April 2019) - "elementary OS must be configured in order for Launchpad to forward bugs to the project's developers." - we're now supposed to report them in GitHub? https://elementary.io/docs/code/reference#reporting-bugs

Answer (score 5):

Try `nmcli radio wifi on` through terminal

Comment: This worked for me while `rfkill` didn't give proper output, was searching from long time. Using usb WiFi adaptor.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I also have some issues with wireless on Loki. What I did:

1. Open the terminal/console and type:

   ```
   rfkill list all
   ```

   You should probably get a result like this:

   ```
   0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
           Soft blocked: yes
           Hard blocked: no
   1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no
   2: hci0: Bluetooth
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no
   3: phy0: Wireless LAN
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no
   4: nfc0: NFC
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no
   ```

   So as you can see Wireless LAN has status: Soft blocked: yes
2. Now run in the terminal the command:

   ```
   rfkill unblock 0 
   /* 
   * or another number which coresponde to your wi-fi (example: sony-wifi):
   * rfkill unblock <number>
   */
   ```
3. If the wireless is still off try to reboot your PC and check if wireless is on. If not try again the first steps.

Comment: I have run the commend on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) i found 0: bluetooth: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no only